# Rotating a fractal tree with branches in p5js by x-axis

Tags: javascript, recursion, rotation, p5.js, fractals

I'm a newbie in coding and I have been playing with Fractal tree and OOP from the Coding Train videos.

The tree is generated as object trunks with its child branches in constructor function.

```js
class Branch {
  constructor(begin, end) {
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
    this.finished = false;
  }

  jitter() {
    this.end.x += random(-1, 1);
    this.end.y += random(-1, 1);
  }

  show() {
    stroke(255);
    line(this.begin.x, this.begin.y, this.end.x, this.end.y);
  }

  branchA() {
    let dir = p5.Vector.sub(this.end, this.begin);
    dir.rotate(PI / 6);
    dir.mult(0.67);
    let newEnd = p5.Vector.add(this.end, dir);
    let b = new Branch(this.end, newEnd);
    return b;
  }

  branchB() {
    let dir = p5.Vector.sub(this.end, this.begin);
    dir.rotate(-PI / 4);
    dir.mult(0.67);
    let newEnd = p5.Vector.add(this.end, dir);
    let b = new Branch(this.end, newEnd);
    return b;
  }
}

// Fractal Trees - Object Oriented
// Coding Train / Daniel Shiffman
// https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/15-object-oriented-fractal-trees

// https://youtu.be/fcdNSZ9IzJM
// Code from challenge: https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/JDT5wrxVj

let tree = [];
let leaves = [];

let count = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  let a = createVector(width / 2, height);
  let b = createVector(width / 2, height - 100);
  let root = new Branch(a, b);

  tree[0] = root;
}

function mousePressed() {
  for (let i = tree.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!tree[i].finished) {
      tree.push(tree[i].branchA());
      tree.push(tree[i].branchB());
    }
    tree[i].finished = true;
  }
  count++;

  if (count === 6) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
      if (!tree[i].finished) {
        let leaf = tree[i].end.copy();
        leaves.push(leaf);
      }
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(51);

  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    tree[i].show();
    tree[i].jitter();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < leaves.length; i++) {
    fill(255, 0, 100, 100);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(leaves[i].x, leaves[i].y, 8, 8);
    leaves[i].y += random(0, 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried various attempts to no avail.

One that had best outcome was in  the branch class show function

```
show ()
    {
        push();
        translate(this.begin.x, this.begin.y);
        rotate(cos(frameCount/360);
        stroke(255);
        line(0,0, this.end.x - this.begin.x, this.end.y - this.begin.y);
        pop();
        stroke(255);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry--what is the question/problem/request/issue here? Do you want to [rotate the canvas 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073115/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-in-p5js) or is it supposed to gradually rotate? "One that had best outcome..." what was "best" about it and in what way could it be better? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ggorlen Hello, I am sorry for not being clear. 

My intention is to have the fractal rotate around it's x-axis. Such that root of the tree (the base) is fixed, and then whatever the amount of branches get's generated, rotates around in full circle. 

"What was best about it" means that the fractal rotated it's root around x axis, and the generated branches also rotated about their own x-axis, but not as a whole. 

I hope this was a clearer answer.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clarify. Generally speaking, though, the link above should get you working: `push()` the canvas transformation, `translate()` to the area you want the tree to rotate about, `rotate()` by the desired amount, draw the whole tree at the origin (0, 0), `pop()` the canvas and done. The difference between this and your attempt is that you want to do the procedure on _the whole tree_ rather than _each branch_. So basically the push/pop/translate/rotate stuff all happens at the top level of `draw()`, wrapped around all of your tree-drawing operations.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you ggorlen, your assumption is good. I have tried few hours ago doing the exact same thing and got it working!

Comment: Great, feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!