# Rotating Line around Point in p5.js

Tags: javascript, computational-geometry, p5.js

**Goal:** I'm trying to create a triangle given two angles `(a0,b0)`. To do so, I'm trying to rotate a vector `r0` by some angle `a0` *around* one of the vertices of `r0`. Here's a diagram illustrating my idea.
[image]
**Problem:** However, when I rotate the line, it seems to rotate around the origin. I've read [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900807/how-do-i-rotate-a-rectangle-shape-from-a-specific-point-in-p5-js), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139479/rotating-objects-within-a-grid-in-p5-js) [articles](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/21317/rotation-around-fixed-point-by-angle) on how to fix this, but none of the suggested solutions (i.e., translate then rotate, `push()`, `pop()`) don't seem to work, perhaps because I'm dealing with a line segment here. Below is my code.

**MWE Code:**

```js
let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  let v1 = createVector(width / 2 - 50, height / 2);
  let v2 = createVector(width / 2 + 50, height / 2);

  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  let r0 = line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
  rotate(20);
  let r1 = line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
  strokeWeight(10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rotate` rotates around the origin of the coordinate system. To rotate around a pivot point, you must:

- move the pivot to the origin
- rotate the object
- move the pivot back to its place in the scene

```
translate(v1.x, v1.y);
rotate(-1 * mouseX);
translate(-v1.x, -v1.y);
```

```js
let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 300);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  let v1 = createVector(width / 2 - 50, height / 2);
  let v2 = createVector(width / 2 + 50, height / 2);

  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  
  push();
  translate(v1.x, v1.y);
  rotate(-1 * mouseX);
  translate(-v1.x, -v1.y);
  let r0 = line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
  strokeWeight(10);
  let p1 = point(v1.x, v1.y);
  let p2 = point(v2.x, v2.y);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

For individual model transformations, you must `push()` the current matrix before specifying the transformations and `pop()` the matrix after drawing the objects. So you can draw different objects with different transformations.